# How do I find the number of clients with a matrices application?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

> Four competing companies (A, B, C, and D) are competing in a finite market of 5000 clients.
> Each month, the clients can either renew their contract with the company they were with or switch
> companies, according to the following ratios:

> • Company A retains 35% of its clients; 25% go to company B, 15% go to company C, and 25% go
> to company D.

> • Company B retains 50% of its clients; 10% go to company A, 20% go to company C, and 20% go
> to company D.

> • Company C retains 40% of its clients; 40% go to company A, 5% go to company B, and 15% go
> to company D.

> • Company D retains 40% of its clients; 35% go to company A, 15% go to company B, and 10%
> go to company C.

---

> How many clients should each company expect to end up with?

So first what I did was put the numbers into a nice matrix as follows (which each column is a company. first column = company A and last column = company D:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0.35 & 0.1 & 0.4 & 0.35 \\
0.25 & 0.5 & 0.05 & 0.15\\
0.15 & 0.2 & 0.4 & 0.1 \\
0.25 & 0.2 & 0.15 & 0.4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

Then I reduced it, but I just got a trinagluar matrix with 1s and 0s which doesn't help. Here is the answer:

[image]

But I have no clue how they got that. Any ideas? I tried finding the eigen value but that didn't do anything either.

here's my closest I got with my steady-state eigenvector:
[image]

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Can you find the eignenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues of that nice matrix? If yes, please include them.

Comment: @CalvinLin my calculator broke when i was trying to find the eigen vectors for it but ill add how close I got to it

Comment: What multiple of the entries of v will add to 5000?

Comment: @Paul wouldn't it just be 1281 since it's a one-to-one ratio? OOOOOOOOOOOOOOH ok, so the answer is literally just 1281 times each of those numbers and that's the answer. thanks!

Comment: how would i find dat 1281 doe

Comment: Add the components of v and divide into 5000. An eigenvector is only known up to a multiple and you want the multiple which makes the components sum to 5000.